# How to get InfluxDB version via shell

Tags: shell, influxdb

The influx shell has a `-version` flag, but not influx server:

```
/path/to/bin/influx -version
InfluxDB shell version: 1.1.1

/path/to/bin/influxd -version
flag provided but not defined: -version

/path/to/bin/influxd -v
flag provided but not defined: -v
```

Should I assume that influx shell and influx server will always have the same version ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> curl -sL -I localhost:8086/ping

You should get something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: c7c8f7d7-b7ef-11e7-8002-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.3.6
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2017 12:43:33 GMT
```

If you are using HTTPS:

```
curl -skL -I 'https://myhost:8086/ping'
```

Comment: I had to curl with `-v` parameter.

Comment: You might also need to `curl -skL -I 'https://myhost:8086/ping'` if it is using TLS/SSL.

Comment: That's if the server has managed to start. Otherwise, see [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43572737/1269037) answer.

Answer (score 14):

It's most likely that the InfluxDB client and InfluxDB server *on the same server* are the same versions.  If you want to specifically check the server version, you can do so.

In versions 0.11 (at least) and above, the influxdb executable accepts a version argument:

```
% /usr/bin/influxd version
InfluxDB v1.2.1 (git: master 3ec60fe2649b51a85cd1db6c8937320a80a64c35)
```

Answer (score 5):

You also can get influxdb version by sending http request to server.

for example

```
$ curl -G -i http://yourserver.com:8086/query -u anonymous:anonymous --data-urlencode "db=dbname" --data-urlencode "q=SHOW MEASUREMENTS"
```

And result in response headers

```
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.2.3-c1.2.3
```

Comment: This kind of answer was given already in a simpler & faster form. It's also flawed, [as I pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856474/how-to-get-influxdb-version-via-shell#comment121757501_46889735).

Answer (score -2):

Simply type ## influx version ## in terminal

Answer (score -3):

on ssh terminal just type below command

```
influx -version
```

Comment: That's the client, not the server.